# How can I prevent this odd NERDTree behaviour in Neovim?

Tags: nerdtree, neovim

I recently reinstalled `NERDTree` in my Neovim (0.1.7) installation via `vim-plug`. For convenience, I added the common configuration line `au VimEnter * NERDTreeToggle` to my `init.vim`.

This works to a certain extent; it spawns a new vertical split with a standard-NERDTree-Width buffer; however, instead of having a NERDTree, the new, narrower buffer has the contents of the primary buffer (usually the file I'm working on).

Even more strangely, launching NERDTree manually (either using `:NERDTree` or `:NERDTreeToggle`) results in normal, expected behaviour.

I'm not sure what's causing this behaviour; are NERDTree semantics different in Neovim lately? How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not expected.

First off, you really should update Neovim to the latest version. Currently this is 0.2.2. It may be that there are issues with an older version of Neovim. Of course, seeing that this question is from 2013, odds are that you already have.

Apart from updating, please try and run Neovim with a minimal `init.vim`, containing just the plugin and the autocmd. See if this works. If it does (and I bet it will), re-enable plugins and settings one-by-one to determine when the expected behavior breaks again. You will then have found the conflicting plugin or setting.